# Error: Invalid multi-line string terraform

Tags: terraform

I am trying to define a resource but Terraform complains

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "my-functions-order-machine-completion-target" {
  target_id = "some target id"
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.my-functions-order-machine-completion-rule.name
  arn       = module.lambda["myLambda"].function_arn
}
```

**error**:

```
Quoted strings may not be split over multiple lines. To produce a multi-line
string, either use the \n escape to represent a newline character or use the
"heredoc" multi-line template syntax.
```

I saw [Heredoc Strings](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/strings.html#heredoc-strings) but not sure how to use this after "resource"

Comment: There should be a `.name` after the `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.my-functions-order-machine-completion-rule`.

Comment: yeah sorry typo

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with the code shown. What are you trying to do, where, what error happens and where exactly!?

Comment: updated formatting essentially when TF is running it complains that strings cannot be split into multi line

Answer (score 3):

Same issue at my end, but for me there was syntax error. there was duplicate double quotes. Notice the first line number mentioned in error.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a great answer, shortening the name of the resource sorted out the issue for me.

I also tried interpolation syntax like so which did not work:

resource "resource" "${var.name}"